# The relation between $GF(2)$ and $GF(2^3)$

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Both $GF(2)$ and $GF(2^3)$ are finite fields of characteristic $2$.

Is $GL(2^3)$ an extension of $GF(2)$?

Can someone point some links that details something about this, please?

Comment: This can be found in nearly any discussion of finite fields. Since $p(x) := x^3 + x + 1$ is irreducible in $GF(2)$, the ideal it generates in $GF(2)[x]$ is maximal. Thus, $GF(2)[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ is a field of $2^3$ elements and so we may identify it with $GF(2^3)$. In particular, it contains $GF(2)$ as the subfield of (equivalence classes of) constant polynomials.

Comment: @Travis: Is it that for every irreducible polynomial there is equivalence class which is always having a prime characteristics and there can be multiple irreducible polynomials sharing same equivalence class, same as multiples ideals might represent same algebraic variety.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the questions, but: (1) For all primes $p$ and positive integers $n$ there is a polynomial of degree $n$ that is irreducible modulo $p$, in which case one can play the same game as in my previous comment, (2) there is only one field up to isomorphism of order $p^n$, and (2) for most $(p, n)$ there is more than one such polynomial (the only exception I know is $p = n = 2$, I'd guess this is the only one).

Answer (score 1):

This can be found in nearly any discussion of finite fields.

Here's a standard way to realize an embedding $GL(2) \hookrightarrow GL(2^3)$. Since $p(x):=x^3+x+1$ is irreducible in $GF(2)$, the ideal it generates in $GF(2)[x]$ is maximal. Thus, $GF(2)[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field with $2^3$ elements and so we may identify it with $GF(2^3)$. In particular, it contains $GF(2)$ as the subfield of (equivalence classes of) constant polynomials.

In general one can play the same game to realize $GL(p^{kn})$ as an extension of $GL(p^n)$ for any $p, n, k$.

For a little more about this, see, e.g., Dummit & Foote, $\S$13.

Comment: Dummit says its an extension.